# CKeditor and datepicker not work when the html tag in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, ckeditor

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">   </script>
<script src="../ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#a1").click(function(){
     $('#b1').append('<textarea row=2 class="ckeditor" id="t1"></textarea>');
 });
});

CKEDITOR.replace('t1', { extraPlugins : 'divarea' });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="a1">Click</button>
<div id="b1"></div>
<textarea row=2 class="ckeditor" id="t1"></textarea>
```

Above is my code. The textarea out of JQuery is working fine, but it in JQuery not work. I searched online, used divarea plugin, it still not work...
and same issue on datepicker.

Comment: ck only scans the dom once for things to turn into an editor. it won't notice you added a new one after that scan's completed. you have to trigger a rescan or explicitly tell ck to start using the new textarea.

Comment: Thanks Marc, I already solve it. this is my changed code: $(document).ready(function(){
    number=0;
    $("#a1").click(function(){
        number++;
        $('#b1').append('<textarea row=2 class="ckeditor" id="t' + number + '"></textarea>');
        CKEDITOR.replace('t' + number, { extraPlugins : 'divarea' });
        CKEDITOR.add;
    });    
});

Comment: But for datepicker issue I still have no idea.